# Iterable java list roundrobin concurrency issues

Tags: java, concurrency

I have several cases where I need to set up a `List` and then Iterate over them in a roundrobin fashion.  I am relatively new to multi threading so I am learning as I go.

Today I started getting some concurrency issues.

```
Exception in thread "LogThing: 25" Exception in thread "LogThing: 27" Exception in thread "LogThing: 21" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$2.next(Iterators.java:418)
    at com.example.my.RoundRobinIterable.getNext(RoundRobinIterable.java:22)
    at com.example.my.EpsSendingStrategy.run(EpsSendingStrategy.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Now the RoundRobbinIterable is quite simple.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

public class RoundRobinIterable<T> {
  private final Iterator<T> elements;

  public RoundRobinIterable(final List<T> elements) {
    this.elements = Iterables.cycle(elements).iterator();
  }

  public synchronized T getNext() {
    return this.elements.next();;
  }

}
```

Now EpsSendingStrategy.java has a `static RoundRobinIterable<PrintWriter> writerIterable` and as you can see from the stacktrace it is also a thread.  When I create my `RoundRobinIterable` I pass in  `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` with some values.  Line 22 happens to be `writer = writerIterable.getNext();`

So somehow `getNext()` is causing a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` exception

EDIT 1:

```
public class EpsSendingStrategy extends SendingStrategy {

  public EpsSendingStrategy(LogDosSettings settings) {
    super(settings);
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(EpsSendingStrategy.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    createConnections();
    startSending.set(System.nanoTime());
    PrintWriter writer;

    while (sendMessages) {
      logger.debug("about to write message");
      writer = writerIterable.getNext();
      writer.println(settings.getMessage());
      writer.flush();

      lastSent.set(startSending.get() + logItoration.get() * 1000000000L / settings.getEps());
      while (System.nanoTime() < lastSent.get());

      logItoration.incrementAndGet();
    }
  }

}
```

Edit 2: I also tried the same synchronization used on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493759/2599884 but this was also a bust.  There is something deeper that I am not understanding.

Comment: Can we see `EpsSendingStrategy`?

Comment: @JacobG. I have included it.  It extends SendingStrategy that has the writerIterable in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ConcurrentModificationException** is thrown because you iterate over the list while some threads add an element into the list.

You are using **Collections.synchronizedList**, where add and remove methods are synchronized by the list lock. To forbid the others to add something to the list while you are iterating the list with the iterator you have to lock that list like this.

```
synchronized(list){
Iterator i = list.iterator(); 
      while (i.hasNext()){
        //do something
  }
}
```

You are not doing this, you are synchronizing **getNext** method but not with the list lock and you are synchronizing only when you call the **next()** method which is not enough.

```
 public synchronized T getNext() {
    return this.elements.next();;
  }
```

If you want to use your pattern you have to create the copy of the list in your RoundRobinIterable

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

public class RoundRobinIterable<T> {
  private final Iterator<T> elements;

  public RoundRobinIterable(final List<T> elements) {
    List<T> copyOfElements = new ArrayList<>(elements);
    this.elements = Iterables.cycle(copyOfElements).iterator();
  }

  public synchronized T getNext() {
    return this.elements.next();;
  }
}
```

Now nobody can add an element into the copied list while you are iterating the list, but you will not get the elements that you add to the original list after you created the RoundRobinIterable. If you want to get the elements that are added later, then it's better to use something else than List. For example **ConcurrentLinkedQueue.**

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the javadoc of [Collections.synchronizedList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)):-

```
Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
```

But you are passing your synchronized list to guava in this line:-

```
this.elements = Iterables.cycle(elements).iterator();
```

which [I think](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.java) doesn't use synchronization while calling `.iterator()`. Also, it can call it at a time not controlled by you (like when you are modifying it).

While this answer may point you in the right direction, it might be worth waiting for a more definitive answer by someone (I've never used Guava).

Comment: That is interesting.  I still don't get why the sync on the method did not stop the issue but it does give me something to go on.

Comment: @buzzsawddog sync on the `getNext()` method? what about the call to `.iterator()`? that doesn't seem to be synchronized.

Comment: In the last little bit I have kind of rethought what I am doing based on the research I have done.  I made the decisions I made due to lack of experience ;-)  I am going to try something else out and if that does not work come back to your idea.